# Can someone explain EasyRSA Vars options

Tags: certificate-authority

The other question is old and doesn't explain anything

Can someone explain and give the list of what we can fill for these variable ?

```
set HOME=%ProgramFiles%\OpenVPN\easy-rsa
set KEY_CONFIG=openssl-1.0.0.cnf
set KEY_DIR=keys
set DH_KEY_SIZE=2048
set KEY_SIZE=4096
set KEY_COUNTRY=US
set KEY_PROVINCE=CA
set KEY_CITY=SanFrancisco
set KEY_ORG=OpenVPN
set KEY_EMAIL=mail@host.domain
set KEY_CN=changeme
set KEY_NAME=changeme
set KEY_OU=changeme
set PKCS11_MODULE_PATH=changeme
set PKCS11_PIN=1234
```

---

**the business problem you are working on :** I'm trying to set-up a certificate to establish a secure VPN tunnel between my home and my work

**the research you have done :** I have searched about the different protocols to accomplish that in a secure way, and the VPN fit to my conditions because i can communicate using sub-protocols who are not encrypted. After i've searched for a tutorial to set-up a VPN server and here i'm on the step about configuring EasyRSA

**the steps taken so far to solve it :** To solve my problem i've tried to search the different strings on internet, and i've only found a list for KEY_COUNTRY one

---

It's not a question about "product, service, or learning material recommendations". It's a question about X.509 specificity.

This question will not attract " low quality, opinionated and spam answers" but definition about all variable and what we can fill, there's no opinion about variable, it's a non-sense.

The answer will not become quickly obsolete, the answer will stay true for X.509 forever, and will be useful until a new protocol replace it (a lot of years).

I know it's a documentation asking, but i couldn't find it on internet, do you have any clues ?

Answer (score 0):

C=US was originally defined by RFC 1218. I have been developing policies that apply to the domain, but if you are creating a certificate simply to enable encryption and not attempting to get other Relying Parties to trust your own self signed certificate you can easily supply acceptable values. Certificates which are relied upon by other parties have highly defined values with defined certificate policy statements which can be downloaded from certificate authorities to create trust. The x.500 and x.509v3 standards are available for download that define all these fields.